# Ajaxian HTML to PDF print control

Tags: html, ajax, pdf

Is there an AJAX control for converting HTML pages into PDF?

I'd like to add a "printer-friendly" link which creates a PDF file of the current page.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this free service [web2pdfconvert](http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/), which relies on [this service](http://www.freepdfconvert.com/)

A link runs over ajax to return the current page as PDF, and is very accurate in terms of layout and rendering.

Here is the script to embed for the super-lazy :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pdfbuttonlabel="Save page as PDF"
</script>

<script src="http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/pdfbutton.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```